# Is it possible to Make Mac OS ignore keyboard shortcuts while using Windows under VMWare Fusion?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, visual-studio

I just got my MacBook Air, max RAM, Harddrive and CPU. I have installed Windows 7 using bootcamp and are also using win7 from my Mac OS.

My question: Is it possible to be in the Windows7 machine, and for example pressing Ctrl-Right Arrow or any other shortcut in Windows and have Mac OS ignore that input ?

Another example is Ctrl-space which I use a lot in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this is Fusion's global preferences.
[image]

Comment: Alternatively, you can always change Mac OS X shortcuts in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. Your virtualization program might have something like an "Exclusive mode" which basically redirects all inputs to the virtual OS and binds the screen borders so that your mouse will not escape the virtual OS.

Comment: Great, thank you. This was exactly was I needed